# R shiny: how to get ggplot to use a variable in it's aes() when aes_string() alternate does not work

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am writing a shiny app and using ggplot to plot a density map. Unfortunately, I am not able to get ggplot to understand my input variable in the aes() section. Below is a part of the code that is problematic in my server.R:

```
  output$mapPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=Robbery,aes(x=X.Coordinate.Code,y=Y.Coordinate.Code),environment = .e) +  
     stat_density2d(aes(fill=..density..,alpha=cut(..density..,breaks=c(0,input$ranged,Inf))),
                     geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) 
 })
```

The error output is :  Error in cut.default: object 'input' not found

The input variable that I want to pass is input$ranged. I have seen the suggestion of using aes_string() instead of aes() when using a variable like this.  My problem is that when I use aes_string() it is not able to understand what ..density.. is.  Is there another way to get ggplot to accept the input$ranged variable other then using aes_string()?

Thank you very much.

Note: when I just print out the input$ranged variable in my app, it works fine. Here is the server.R code for just printing input$ranged:

```
output$mapText = renderText({
    paste("the cutoff is",input$ranged)
  })
```

Here is a little R code I've added that can be run to reproduce the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

    set.seed(42)
    df =  data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2000), nrow=1000))
    df
    ggplot(data= df,aes(x=X1,y=X2)) + geom_point() +
      stat_density2d(aes(fill=..density..,alpha=cut(..density..,breaks=c(0,0.02,Inf))),geom = "raster", contour = FALSE)

    test=0.02

    ggplot(data= df,aes(x=X1,y=X2)) + geom_point() +
      stat_density2d(aes(fill=..density..,alpha=cut(..density..,breaks=c(0,test,Inf))),geom = "raster", contour = FALSE)
```

The "test" variable is not understood by ggplot.  But, if I use aes_string() instead of aes(), the ..density.. is not understood.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. This probably isn't specific to shiny. But it's unclear even what value `input$ranged` contains.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, Note taken.  Sorry, it's my first time posting.  Here is a simple R code (No Shiny) where the problem is reproduced. So in this case, when I try to pass the "test" variable to ggplot, it's not able to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's one other member of the `aes()` family, called `aes_q()`. Because you need to build an expression here, I think the would be the easiest to use. For example

```
test <- 0.02
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=X1,y=X2)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_density2d(aes_q(
      fill = quote(..density..), 
      alpha = bquote(cut(..density..,breaks=c(0, .(test), Inf)))
      ), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE)
```

Here we use `bquote` to "insert" the numeric value into the breaks expression. If we look at just that chunk we see we get the expression we want

```
bquote(cut(..density..,breaks=c(0,.(test),Inf)))
# cut(..density.., breaks = c(0, 0.02, Inf))
```

Depending on how you defined your Shiny input, you'll also want to make sure it's numeric (many are character values by default). So you may need to use `as.numeric(input$ranged)`

Comment: This worked perfectly.  In the example as well as in my shiny app.  Thank you MrFlick!